# android earth quake app using app

Tags: android

ok so i have developed an earthquake api app and it is working fine.now i have a doubt creeped into my  mind.i have used an http request method that requests from the server and uses a json response.but i cant find the usage of any port no in my code.there should be some tcp connection using port no right.is this handled by android ide itself.i have attached the code used in the method.can anyone help me out

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();.

            // If the request was successful (response code 200),
            // then read the input stream and parse the response.
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
            } else {
 Log.e(SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE, "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE, "Problem retrieving the earthquake JSON results.", e);
        }
        finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                // Closing the input stream could throw an IOException, which is why
                // the makeHttpRequest(URL url) method signature specifies than an IOException
                // could be thrown.
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }
```

Comment: sending and receiving post/get doesnt use ports. if you are worried about security, set it up using an API key... without the API key, itll never work.

Comment: Technically DroiDev isn't quite right: HTTP uses port 80 for insecure connections, 443 for TLS/SSL connections.  Generally you can ignore that though, unless you want to hit a _specific_ port.  In that case, you can do a GET/POST/PUT/whatever to http://yourserverhere.com:<portnumber>.  Ex: http://earthquakes.com:8080 will use port 8080 to do the HTTP communication.

Comment: so that means it uses default ports right so therefore no need of mentioning it seperately.??

Comment: what about the sockets no need for mentioning sockets also??